# Delete Substring with regex

Tags: regex, replace, substring

I want to delete each substring in brackets in a String, for example

> This is a (simple) text (or an example text). Thank you!

to

> This is a text. Thank you!

I want to do it with replace but I can't find a properly working regExpression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the result of following regex :

```
\s?\([^)]+\)
```

with an empty string.

Comment: Here: `This is a (simple)) text (or an example text). Thank you!` it will fail with `This is a ) text. Thank you!`

Comment: @streetturtle Yep you are right but such problems can have a lot of scenario, so I just gave a n answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
\s?\(.*?\)\s?
```

by space. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lU5wD2/2

Comment: Have you tried the example you gave in @Kasramvd answer? _https://regex101.com/r/lU5wD2/3_

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex you need:

```
 / \(.+\)/
```

And you will need to use it with replace like this:

```
 str = str.replace(/ \(.+\)/, "");
```